# Getting selected text from UIMenuController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm trying to get the selected text when performing actions with a UIMenuController.  How do I get the selected text out?  I'm using a UIWebView at the moment, but would like a universal solution if there is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get the data from `UIPasteboard`. It should be something like `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string` for text.

Comment: That gets what's been copied.  I'm not copying the text, just need to use it.

Comment: @btate Got what you were looking for. You can call `[self.webView copy:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];` to send the text onto the pasteboard and then the above command works without him actually copying. This should work for any `UIResponder` subclass that implements `copy:`.

Comment: This works beautifully.  Thanks.  I also found this which works with javascript. `return [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];`