# How to get selection text from UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

, Hello, everyone.

I'm developing my app which has a feature to post article from website.

This is a picture of UIWebview with UIMenuController.

[image]

It was possible to get event when user tap the button. but I can't find the way to get the text the user selected.

In UITextView case, it has 'selectedRange' property, so it is easy to get selection text.

```
UIMenuItem *facebookMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" action:@selector(facebookMenuItemTapped:)];
UIMenuItem *twitterMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter" action:@selector(twitterMenuItemTapped:)];

[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: facebookMenuItem, twitterMenuItem, nil];

[twitterMenuItem release];
[facebookMenuItem release];
```

I would like to get the selection text on UIWebView.
Does anybody have an idea or hint?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting selected text from UIMenuController.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192465/getting-selected-text-from-uimenucontroller)

Answer (score 14):

Or if you donʾt want to mess with Javascript you can just copy the selection to the pasteboard and then retrieve it by running:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(copy:) to:nil from:self forEvent:nil];
    NSString *text =  [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string;
```

Comment: Can someone please explain how to use it? I could not get it work.

Comment: Can we get the attributes of the selected text? Like bold text and other?