# Find elements with webkit-tap-highlight

Tags: javascript, css, uiwebview, safari, webkit

When you tap and hold on a link inside a UIWebView (or mobile safari), it highlights the link in a gray text box.

You can control the styling of this with the webkit-tap-highlight css property.

What I'd like to know is if it is possible to either:
A. Listen to an event for when something is highlighted.
B. At a given time, find any elements that are currently highlighted.

Is this currently possible?

Comment: Can you use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection)? (Sorry, never developed specically for mobile safari...)

Comment: Was 'this' suppose to be a link?

Comment: ['this'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) is a link...

Comment: haha, sorry, totally missed that. Yea I tried window.getSelection it doesn't seem to grab highlighted text. Only when the text is actually selected.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can you just [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8092444/781199) (<- HINT THAT IS A LINK ;) ) and then bind the touch start touch end events to highlight the object and call whatever functions you originally wanted called... (i.e. basically rewrite the whole process in js)?

Comment: That could work but ideally I wouldn't have to modify the page that is being displayed. Thanks for that though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this guy figured it out using `window.getSelection()` and `text.anchorNode.textContent.substr(text.anchorOffset, text.focusOffset - text.anchorOffset)`:

http://zaldzbugz.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/how-to-get-the-highlighted-text-in-uiwebview/

This article was also chosen as a working answer in another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260926/how-to-get-selection-text-from-uiwebview).

Answer (score 0):

Although the iPhone is a touch device, the mouseover event will be triggered when the element is highlighted. So, you can use javascript to listen the mouseover event.