# dynamic highlighting using javascript/uiwebview ios

Tags: javascript, ios, dynamic, uiwebview, highlighting

I have some text content displayed on a UIWebView which is plain html. The current paragraph is highlighted in yellow and the user has selected the word 'If the'. (link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKp9h.png)

1) When the user selects some text on the uiwebiew, how do I perform dynamic highlighting? i.e. as the user is selecting text, what ever text is selected gets highlighted in purple?

For instance, I like the words 'If the' to be highlighted in purple (maybe using window.getSelection() ? ) and that this behaviour is dynamic such that as the user selects subsequent words, these words under selection gets highlighted in purple.

**What I am struggling with at the moment is:**

1) What event handler (JavaScript or iOS) should I listen to, when the user is selecting some text on the uiwebview? This is before the uimenucontroller opens up.

2) Once, I get the selected text (using window.getSelection(), how do I modify the DOM in a clean efficient way such that the selected text gets highlighted?

I suppose for 2) I cannot directly use `style.backgroundColor=<hex code of purple>`

Comment: Can you style the text using the `::selection` CSS selector? (cf. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp)

Comment: thanks this is super helpful. I am not sure if this is supported for span elements? This may be supported only in textarea? Also do you know if this is supported in Safari/iOS?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. It works fine on a desktop, but does not work on iOS :-(

Comment: sorry--if i was more confident I would have posted a real answer :) does it have to be a web view? I know for sure you can get the selection area for other iOS text views.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very similar question here: [How to get selection text from UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260926/how-to-get-selection-text-from-uiwebview)

From the accepted answer there, looks like this might answer your question: http://zaldzbugz.posterous.com/how-to-mark-or-get-the-highlighted-string-ins/ There's a discussion about getting and styling the text selection in a web view.

Comment: thanks. I did have a look earlier at that link. Unfortunately it was't much help. I guess what I am struggling with at the moment are 1) What event handler (JavaScript or iOS) should I listen to, when the user is selecting some text on the uiwebview? This is before the uimenucontroller opens up. 2) Once, I get the selected text (using window.getSelection(), how do I modify the DOM in a clean efficient way such that the selected text gets highlighted? I suppose for 2) I cannot directly use style.backgroundColor=<hex code of purple>